# Recreating phone back glass / plastic

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes, glass

I've been trying to recreate a back glass/plastic material based on my phone, which this picture could be an example on how it looks under bright light

[image: Picture of General Mobile GM 22 Plus, which has a plastic back and the light reflected from the plastic is seen have a semi-anisotropic like shape]

(This picture isn't mine, but I am willing to provide more images myself if needed)

This picture isn't mine, but I am willing to provide more images myself if neededI've tried to get a similar effect with two Anisotropic BDSFs and a Glass BDSF mixed together as seen below, but I am not very satisfied with this effect.
[image: Less similar effect mentioned above]
[image: Shader nodes]
I've also tried to change the Texture Coordinate outputs with different values but it doesn't seem to help very much.

I would really appreciate if my mistakes are pointed out or improvements are told, thanks.

Comment: One of the main problems here is a lack of environment for it to reflect.  Try an HDRI background

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate your phone to create the plastic protection object, sculpt it a bit to give it some bumps, give it transparency with the Principled BSDF *Transmission* value at 1, plug a *Noise Texture* into the *Roughness* to create a bit of variation in its glossiness:

[image]